# Conditionally counting while also grouping by

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, group-by

I am trying to join two tables

```
ad_data_grouped
adID, adDate (date), totalViews
```

This is data that has already been grouped by both adID and adDate.
The second table is

```
leads
leadID, DateOfBirth, adID, state, createdAt(dateTime)
```

What I'm struggling with is joining these two tables so I can have a column that counts the number of leads when it shares the same adID and where the adDate = createdAt
The problem I'm running into is that when the counts are all the same for all groupings of adID....I have a few other things I'm trying to do, but it's based on similar similar conditional counting.

Query:(I know the temp table is probably overkill, but I'm trying to break this up into small pieces where I can understand what each piece does)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ad_stats_grouped
SELECT * FROM `ad_stats`
LIMIT 0;

INSERT INTO ad_stats_grouped(AdID, adDate, DailyViews)
SELECT
    AdID,
    adDate,
    sum(DailyViews)
FROM `ad_stats`
    GROUP BY adID, adDate;

SELECT
    ad_stats_grouped.adID,
    ad_stats_grouped.adDate,
    COUNT(case when ad_stats_grouped.adDate = Date(Leads.CreatedAt) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM `ad_stats_grouped` INNER JOIN `LEADS` ON
    ad_stats_grouped.adID = Leads.AdID
    GROUP BY adID, adDate;
```

Comment: If you want to copy the structure of a table, use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ad_stats_grouped LIKE ad_stats`.

Comment: `COUNT` should be `SUM`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your original query is the logic in the `COUNT()`. This aggregate functions takes in account all non-`null` values, so it counts `0` *and* `1`s. One solution would be to change `COUNT()` to `SUM()`.

But I think that the query can be furtermore improved by moving the date condition on the date to the `on` part of a `left join`:

```
select
    g.adid,
    g.addate,
    count(l.adid) 
from `ad_stats_grouped` g
left join `leads` l 
    on g.adid = l.adid
    and l.createdat >= g.addate
    and l.createdat <  g.ad_stats + interval 1 day
group by g.adid, g.addate;
```